# Drupal 8 - multi line form

Tags: drupal-8

I want to build a form which serves our IT requests process.

Fields would be..

- Request description (1 per request)
- ***Items required (Item + Qty + Cost + ADD NEW LINE)***
- Overall total Cost (1 per request)

How would I build the ITEMS REQUIRED bit?

Where the 3 fields could be recreated under the previous line

Answer (score 0):

https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection

This module will solve your problem. 
With this module you are able to define multiple fields as one group when you click for add more item then new group of same fields will be display as new item.
 
Read project desc care fully.